# Unix /Linux show the last part of a file with line numbers

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, tail

Is there a way to make tail show a line number in front of the last lines it show so that it show the growth of the file when using it in a script.

e.g: when using it in a script like this one:

```
while [-z $(ps -p $pid) ]; do
   echo  "process is running"
   .....
   tail process.logfile
   sleep 15
   clear
done
```

out put should be:

**111** line 111
**112** line 112
**113** line 113
**114** line 114
**115** line 115
....

and the next round it should be: 
**116** line 116
**117** line 117
**118** line 118
**119** line 119
**120** line 120
...

Comment: What about using `tail -f` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tail itself doesn't have a line numbering capability, but other utilities do. This is a typical solution:

cat -n process.logfile | tail

Comment: Ok I never tought of that! This is somewhat shamefull, form me.  Thanks for the quick answer.  It is exactly what I need.